# Remove elements from the list of one column that are not included in the list of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
data=[['p1', 'p1', 0], ['p2', 'p1', 0], ['p3', 'p1', 0], ['p4', 'p2', 0], ['p5', 'p6', 0],
     ['p6', 'p6', 1],  ['p7', 'p8', 1],  ['p9', 'p6', 1],  ['p10', 'p9', 1],  ['p8', 'p9', 1],['p9', 'p9', 2], ['p10', 'p12', 2], ['p11', 'p13', 2]]
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['id_first', 'id_second', 'group'])
sdf.show()
+--------+---------+-----+
|id_first|id_second|group|
+--------+---------+-----+
|      p1|       p1|    0|
|      p2|       p1|    0|
|      p3|       p1|    0|
|      p4|       p2|    0|
|      p5|       p6|    0|
|      p6|       p6|    1|
|      p7|       p8|    1|
|      p9|       p6|    1|
|     p10|       p9|    1|
|      p8|       p9|    1|
|      p9|       p9|    2|
|     p10|      p12|    2|
|     p11|      p13|    2|
+--------+---------+-----+
```

I group and collect in a list

```
 sdf2 = sdf.groupby('group').agg(F.collect_list('id_first').alias('lst_first'),
                               F.collect_list('id_second').alias('lst_second')) \
    .sort(F.col('group'))
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|group|lst_first            |lst_second          |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|0    |[p4, p5, p1, p2, p3] |[p2, p6, p1, p1, p1]|
|1    |[p6, p9, p7, p10, p8]|[p6, p6, p8, p9, p9]|
|2    |[p9, p10, p11]       |[p9, p12, p13]      |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to see **which elements are not included from** `lst_second` to `lst_first`. They must be deleted and at the same time **delete the same position** in the `lst_first` column. So the result will be

```
  +-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|group|lst_first            |lst_second          |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|0    |[p4, p1, p2, p3]     |[p2, p1, p1, p1]    |
|1    |[p6, p9 , p10, p8]   |[p6, p6, p9, p9]    |
|2    |[p9]                 |[p9]                |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: In first row p4 is not intersecting but is not removed, same for p8/p10 in second row - is this correct?

Comment: Yes, because I see if there are elements of lst_second in lst_first.Perhaps I was mistaken in saying that this is an intersection

Comment: p4 is missing from lst_second and this is normal, but p6 is missing from lst_first, which is bad and should be removed

Comment: ok so why p5 is dropped? Its the same case as p4 imo

Comment: p5 is removed because P6 is not in lst_first. We removed p6 in lst_second and at the same time we remove the same position in lst_first. So that why p5 is dropped

Comment: in group 0 why p3 isn't removed from lst_first, it only exist in lst_first and not lst_second ? same problem for second row, the example doesn't match the description !

Comment: because p3 is not in lst_second. I'm only looking at the elements INSIDE lst_second . I'm not interested in the case when lst_first has it and lst_second doesn't. p3 is left because it has p1 which is in the lst_first list

Comment: what would you do if `lst_first =[p9, p9, p11]` and `lst_second = [p9, p12, p13]` ? would `p9` from lst_first get deleted?

Comment: Only the second p9 will be deleted in this case. The first p9 will remain. Here it is important to delete the position and not the ID itself, I think in lst_first

Comment: In the second row, why p8 was deleted from lst_second ? It exists in lst_first !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `udf` that takes `lst_first` and `lst_second` as inputs, determines the positions of elements of lst_second that aren't in lst_first, and removes these elements from both lists.

The expected output matches yours (except for the second row, which I believe should retain all elements in both lst_first and lst_second, as mentioned in a comment by @Abdennacer Lachiheb).

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType

compare_arrays_udf = F.udf(lambda arr, arr_ref: (
    [arr_ref[j] for j in [i for i,x in enumerate(arr) if x in arr_ref]],
    [arr[j] for j in [i for i,x in enumerate(arr) if x in arr_ref]]
), StructType([
    StructField("lst_first", F.ArrayType(F.StringType()), False),
    StructField("lst_second", F.ArrayType(F.StringType()), False)
]))

sdf2.withColumn(
    'reduced_lsts',compare_arrays_udf(F.col('lst_second'),F.col('lst_first'))
).select(
    F.col('reduced_lsts.lst_first').alias('lst_first'),
    F.col('reduced_lsts.lst_second').alias('lst_second'),
)

+---------------------+--------------------+
|lst_first            |lst_second          |
+---------------------+--------------------+
|[p1, p2, p3, p4]     |[p1, p1, p1, p2]    |
|[p6, p7, p9, p10, p8]|[p6, p8, p6, p9, p9]|
|[p9]                 |[p9]                |
+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use also RDD to get the desired result.

Imports

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

1. Your final DataFrame (sdf2):

```
sdf2 = sdf1.groupby("group").agg(
            collect_list("id_first").alias("lst_first"),
            collect_list("id_second").alias("lst_second")) \
            .sort("group")
```

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|group|           lst_first|          lst_second|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    0|[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]|[p1, p1, p1, p2, p6]|
|    1|[p6, p7, p9, p10,...|[p6, p8, p6, p9, p9]|
|    2|      [p9, p10, p11]|      [p9, p12, p13]|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

2. Convert DataFrame into RDD and perform transformation on top of it

```
sdf3 = sdf2.rdd.map(lambda row: (
        row[0],
        row[1],
        [second for second in row[2] if second in row[1]])
        ).toDF(sdf2.columns)

sdf3.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|group|lst_first            |lst_second          |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
|0    |[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5] |[p1, p1, p1, p2]    |
|1    |[p6, p7, p9, p10, p8]|[p6, p8, p6, p9, p9]|
|2    |[p9, p10, p11]       |[p9]                |
+-----+---------------------+--------------------+
```